# Make grep colour only capture groups

Tags: colors, grep

How do I only **colour** text in **grep** that has been matched by a **group**?

Example:

```
printf "Jon Skeet" | grep -P "Sk(.)(?:\1t)"
```

Prints out "Jon **Skeet**" (with "Skeet" coloured).

I want it to colour only the first 'e' (ie. "Jon Sk**e**et").

**EDIT**:

```
printf "zazbzcz" | grep -P "(.)((?<=.)\1){3}"
```

prints out nothing, but how can I have it print out

**z**a**z**b**z**c**z**

**EDIT 2:**

Perhaps I wasn't clear.

This will be run in a script where I want it to highlight as follows (therefore I will not know where and which letter or number it will be):

**s**d**s**f**s**i**s**j

asd**l**w**l**xa**l**e**l**doxwy

pqk**5**z**5**x**5**c**5**w**5**qas

Note: it will always be exactly one character that needs to be highlighted
(in an ambiguous case, any of them may be highlighted)

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you have an input string and want to colour a specific character? Not likely, since in `Skeet` you only want to colour the first `e`. What is it then?

Answer (score 1):

Grep colours everything that matched, you can't make it colour just capture groups. If you want to highlight just that single letter, but use the same regular expression, you can use a positive look-ahead so it doesn't become part of the match:

```
grep -P '(?<=Sk)(.)(?=\1t)'
```

Comment: Added test case

Comment: @AvdnhracNTAd9ex Not sure what the test case tries to match, but if the requirement really is "highlight capture groups in the match", then grep can't do it. Are you building something like the highlighter on https://regex101.com?

Comment: I don't require the use of grep, I just thought it would be easier. Built-ins are preferred over third-party

Comment: Added new test cases

Answer (score 0):

For the second part:

```
printf "zazbzcz" | grep --color=always "z"
```

prints out the results you want.  It did for me, at least.

I have not figured out the right regex to only color the first instance of a character which is what you want for the first part. I do know that

```
printf "Jon Skeet" | grep --color=always "e"
```

prints out both `e` being colored.

**Edit:** To allow for variables using Bash.

`string_name=zazbzcz
 variable_name=z
 printf $string_name | grep --color=always $variable_name`

I hope this helps you.

**Edit 2**

The following is a bash script that takes 2 arguments.

The first argument takes string or text.
The second argument takes a character to colorize.

`#!/bin/bash
text=${1}
char_colorized=${!#}
printf $text | grep --color=always $char_colorized`

So if you call your file colorize.sh and you have already made it executable. (chmod)

All you should need to do is the following:

./colorize.sh zazbzcz z

This is the best I can do to answer the question as I understand it.

Again, I hope it helps.

Comment: This works only if 'z' and 'e' are constant (but in my case, it might be 'a' or even 'g')

Comment: Thank you Benjamin W, for the edited.

AvdnhracNTAd9ex, You could make it a variable.